# Bash Variable expansion and User Input from the user

Tags: bash, shell, variables, while-loop

Is there a better way of Variable expansion in bash, i am just reading through and learning. I have below code where i am retaining the header line of the command because when we used to grep from the command it used to lost and we get only `grepped` data. However, i'm also looking for input as a file to be given by the user and then read the file line by line.

Is there a better way doing this, please advise.

### Code

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Output file for bhost output redirection
OUTFILE="/home/nxf59093/$(hostname -s)_bhost_out.log"

# Variable for bhosts command
BHST="/opt/lsf/bin/bhosts"

# Just to take the heaer line of the bhosts command & redirect to OUTFILE
"${BHST}"  -w | head -n 1 > "${OUTFILE}"

# Input file name argument to be given along with script execution
# example: ./get_bhots_report.sh  testfile
filename=$1

# read the file line by line
while read line;
        do
        # stuff to do here
        "${BHST}"  -w | grep $line >> "${OUTFILE}"
done < $filename
```

### Output:

```
HOST_NAME          STATUS          JL/U    MAX  NJOBS    RUN  SSUSP  USUSP    RSV
dpc2425            closed_Full     -     36     36     36      0      0      0
dpc2426            closed_Busy     -     36     31     31      0      0      0
dpc2427            closed_Full     -     36     36     36      0      0      0
```

excuse me if something is not explicit.

Comment: It looks like the whole `while` loop could be replaced by `"$BHST" -w | grep -f "$filename" >> "$OUTFILE"`.

Comment: @BenjaminW., intresting, let me see..

Comment: This works nicely, and found the way to retain the header as well.  `"$BHST" -w | { head -1; grep -f "$filename"; } >> "$OUTFILE"`

Comment: But the only thing i'm looking to read the filename as an input from user.

Comment: You still can have the filename as a parameter, that part doesn't change.

Comment: Yes thats true, but i am looking where it can ask the user like `echo -n "Enter the filename and press [ENTER]: "` and `read file`

Comment: Have a look at the `-p` option for `read` (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read)